# Inner slices are hidden in 3d visualization

Tags: python, plotly

I try to visualize with this code. Parameter 'value' is the 3d ct array (119,116,116)

```
z, y, x = [np.arange(stop=i,step=1) for i in im.shape]
X,Y,Z = np.mgrid[0:im.shape[1], 0:im.shape[2],0:im.shape[0]]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=np.transpose(im,(1,2,0)).flatten(),
    opacity=0.3,
    ))
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

these slices of ct lungs

[image]

but it hides the inner slices, appearing only first and last.

[image]

is there anything I don't do correctly?